# Sort an array of strings based on length in ascending order

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

The question is to print the array of string in accordance with the length of strings in ascending order.

For example

```
input={"vellore","i","from","am"}
output=i am from vellore
```

Here is my code:

```
int n=sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    String[] arr = new String[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        arr[i]=sc.nextLine();
    }
    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    for(String i: arr){
        System.out.print(i+" ");
    }
```

Now I know that my output will come in lexical order that is as "am from i vellore", but I want to get my desired output using sort method. I tried using Collections.sort() as well by using arraylist but I still didn't get my desired output.

I want to get my output using sort method without using the normal approach by comparing the lengths of string and all.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
Comparator
.comparingLong( ( String s ) -> s.codePoints().count() )
.thenComparing( Comparator.naturalOrder() )
```

## Avoid legacy type `char`

The [Answer by Frisch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70912662/642706) is correct in suggesting the use of a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html). However, the method reference seen there, `String::length`, fails with most characters. See [this example](https://ideone.com/xpHmXy). The `String#length` method reports a two-character string like `c` as three, incorrectly.

The failure is because that method depends on `char` which has been legacy since Java 2. As a 16-bit value, the `char` type is physically incapable of representing most of the over 140,000 characters defined in a Unicode.

## Code points

Instead, use Unicode code point integers.

Switch out that method reference for the use of [code points](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) rather than `char` type.

Here we use `String#codePoints` to generate an `IntStream`. That `IntStream` is a stream of each character’s code point number, a value in the range of zero to just over a million. Then we use `IntStream#count` to get a count of the values in that stream, a count of the characters in the original string.

```
    String[] arr = { "a1", "c", "b2", "d4" };
    Arrays
        .sort(
            arr , 
            Comparator
            .comparingLong( ( String s ) -> s.codePoints().count() )
            .thenComparing( Comparator.naturalOrder() )
        );
    System.out.println( Arrays.toString( arr ) );
```

See that [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/okGFzQ).

> [a1, b2, c, d4]

Answer (score 1):

You want a `Comparator`. In this case, you specifically want to start by comparing the `String` lengths. I would suggest you then compare naturally (to break ties). Like,

```
String[] arr = { "vellore", "i", "from", "am" };
Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)
        .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
[i, am, from, vellore]
```

Comment: This code fails with most characters. Example: `String[] arr = { "a1", "b2", "c", "d4" };` yields `[a1, b2, d4, c]`. See example code [run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/xpHmXy).

Comment: @Basil That feels disingenuous. Multibyte characters are "most characters" in only the strictest sense of the term.

Comment: Only about 65,000 of the over 140,000 characters defined in Unicode can be represented by the `char` type, and properly accounted for by the `String#length` method.  140,000 - 65,000 = 75,000. That meets the definition of « most » .